# Node.js built-in dns module functions are basic

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, dns

I'm trying to do simple reverse DNS lookups with the dns module built into Node js (I am using v12.18.0) in my React application, but I can't seem to get past the first step in testing the `reverse` function. Running the following code I noticed I was always getting `0.0.0.0` as the response. The following IP should resolve to something, not found even, but instead it just gives me `0.0.0.0` (not a hostname).

```js
var dns = require('dns');
dns.reverse('192.229.133.221', (err, hosts) => console.log('hosts:', hosts));
```

Using the chrome developer tools it seems the implementation of `reverse` and all other functions (some are not even available, like `getServers`) is this:

```
ƒ () {
  if (!arguments.length) return;
  var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];

  if (callback && typeof callback === 'function') {
    callback(null, '0.0.0.0');
  }
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

After much googling, I've found that it is not possible to run this code is in a browser, hence why the functions appear to have hard-coded implementations. I thought I should update this post just in case.